# Is there a way to disable the default behaviour of ctrl+enter in find and replace in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VScode has an annoying feature where it adds a new line into the text box during find and replace when I press ctrl+enter. I would like to use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+enter to replace all, but when I configure it that way in keyboard shortcuts, it is still inserting a newline before replacing, adding an extra newline to every match that is replaced. Example:
Find: "foo"
Replace: "bar"
Before:

```
foofoofoo
foo
```

Expected result:

```
barbarbar
bar
```

Actual result:

```
bar
bar
bar

bar
```

This is highly infuriating since I've already become accustomed to this keyboard shortcut and it is disrupting my normal workflow. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: default `Replace All` is `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`

Comment: most likely that key is processed by the control of the GUI, there is no key binding for that key in the search box, these boxes are HTML `textarea` tags

Comment: VScode says "Ctrl+Enter now inserts line break instead of replacing all. You can modify the keybinding for editor.action.replaceAll to override this behavior." when I press ctrl+enter. I think that means I probably can change this somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in at least 1.67, probably a version before that.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL+K+S , you will get list of all defaults.
Change whatever you want from the first option in the line of edit.

Comment: I searched for "ctrl+enter" but it didn't come up. I'm using the latest version if that helps.

Comment: Use GUI button provided in replace option or you can use the shortcut of Ctrl+Alt+Enter.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 search for `search.action.replace` or `search.action.replaceAll`